# In Job Step > Properties, only see two tabs: Package and Configuration

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis, ssms

I am trying to set a job step that executes a package to use the 32-bit runtime, as it uses the SQL 10 driver against a SQL 2000 database. The job is running on SQL Server 2012. I see all kinds of examples of how to do this, where the job step properties page has 9 tabs (Set Values, Verification, Command Line, General, Configurations, Command Files, Data Sources, Execution Options and Logging). Execution Options has a checkbox for 32-bit mode.

When I look at my job step, logged in to the server as an Admin, running SSMS as administrator, all I see are two tabs: `Package` and `Configuration`. I deployed the packages using the Project Deployment method. How do I get those other tabs to show up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's on the `Configuration` which then has 3 subtabs: Parameters, Connection Managers and Advanced

[image]

Advanced allows you to specify 32 bit vs 64 bit runtime, change the logging levels, dump on errors and override package properties.

[image]

Comment: Wow, that seems embarrassingly simple! I'll check it on Monday.