# In Job Step > Properties, only see two tabs: Package and Configuration — EncryptSensitiveWithPassword

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssis

I am going to echo another question almost exactly, only my question has a different objective:

[In Job Step > Properties, only see two tabs: Package and Configuration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45070/in-job-step-properties-only-see-two-tabs-package-and-configuration)

I am trying to set a job step that executes a package requiring a package password, since the package protection level is set to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword. The job is running on SQL Server 2014. I see all kinds of examples of how to do this, where the job step properties page has 9 tabs (Set Values, Verification, Command Line, General, Configurations, Command Files, Data Sources, Execution Options and Logging). Command Line allows me to enter the password (with the /DECRYPT command line option).

When I look at my job step, logged in to the server as an Admin, running SSMS as administrator, all I see are two tabs: Package and Configuration. I deployed the packages using the Project Deployment method. How do I get those other tabs to show up?

(My ultimate goal is to give the SQL Agent who runs the job access to a MySQL DB password, and I understand setting the package protection level to EncryptSensistiveWithPassword is the correct way to do that, but I cannot find another way to provide the package password.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the job step properties after selecting `SQL Server Integration Services Package` as the type, switch `Package source` to `SSIS Package Store` to get the 9 tabs. `SSIS Catalog` is the default and only has 2 tabs.

`SSIS Package Store`:

[image]

`SSIS Catalog` (the default):

[image]